# Calling functions in other files in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I have hello.ml that has a length function:

```
let rec length l = 
    match l with
        [] -> 0
    | h::t -> 1 + length t ;;
```

call.ml that uses the function:

```
#use "hello.ml" ;; 

print_int (length [1;2;4;5;6;7]) ;;
```

In interpreter mode (ocaml), I can use `ocaml call.ml` to get the results, but when I tried to compile it with ocamlc or ocamlbuild, I got compilation error.

```
File "call.ml", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Syntax error
```

Then, how to modify the caller, callee, and build command to compile the code into executables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#use` directive only works in the toplevel (the interpreter). In compiled code you should use the module name: `Hello.length`.

I'll show how to build the program from a Unix-like command line. You'll have to adapt this to your environment:

```
$ ocamlc -o call hello.ml call.ml
$ ./call
6
```

Answer (score 3):

### hello.ml

```
let rec length l = 
    match l with
        [] -> 0
    | h::t -> 1 + length t ;;
```

### call.ml

```
open Hello

let () = print_int (Hello.length [1;2;4;5;6;7]) ;;
```

### Build

```
ocamlc -o h hello.ml call.ml
```

or

```
ocamlbuild call.native
```

Comment: Why do you declare a module `Hello` inside your `Hello` module? It's useless and quite confusing...