# How to compile multiple files in OCaml?

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, ocaml

I am currently teaching myself `ocaml` for my programming language class and I am having trouble compiling multiple files in `ocaml`.

I have defined a function in my `get_file_buffer.ml` file

Source code of `get_file_buffer.ml`

```
(* 
   Creating a function that will read all the chars 
   in a file passed in from the command argument.
   And store the results in a char list. 
*)

let read_file char_List =
    let char_in = open_in Sys.argv.(1) in   (* Creating a file pointer/in_channel *)
  try
    while true do
      let c = input_char char_in in         (* Getting char from the file *)
            char_List := c :: !char_List    (* Storing the char in the list *)
    done
  with End_of_file ->
        char_List := List.rev !char_List;   (* End of file was reaching, reversing char list *)
        close_in char_in;                   (* Closing the file pointer/in_channel *)

    (* Need to figure out how to catch if the file was not openned. *)
;;
```

I am trying to call the function in my `main.ml`

Source code of `main.ml`

```
(* Storing the result of read_file to buffer which buffer is a char list reference *)
let buffer = ref [] in
      Get_file_buffer.read_file(buffer);

      print_string "\nThe length of the buffer is: ";
      print_int (List.length !buffer); (* Printing length of the list *)
      print_string ("\n\n");
      List.iter print_char !buffer;    (* Iterating through the list and print each element *)
```

In order to compile the program I am using a `MakeFile`

Makefile content

```
.PHONY: all
all: test

#Rule that tests the program
test: read_test
    @./start example.dat

#Rules that creates executable
read_test: main.cmx get_file_buffer.cmx
    @ocamlc -o start get_file_buffer.cmx mail.cmx

#Rule that creates main object file
main.cmx: main.ml
    @ocamlc -c main.ml

#Rule that creates get_file_buffer object file
get_file_buffer.cmx: get_file_buffer.ml
    @ocamlc -c get_file_buffer.ml
```

When I run the `test` rule of my `Makefile` I get the error:
`Error: Unbound module Get_file_buffer`.

I have been trying to use these question as references:
[Compiling multiple Ocaml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771674/compiling-multiple-ocaml-files) and
[Calling functions in other files in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756989/calling-functions-in-other-files-in-ocaml).

Yet I have not been able to get the program to compile correctly. How would I correctly compile the above code to make the program run correctly?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, your `read_test` rule calls `mail.cmx` instead of `main.cmx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than build *.ml files one by one. You have a couple of better options which are both productive and effective.

**Use ocamlbuild with Makefile like so.**

Rename `main.ml` to `start.ml` and use the following `Makefile`.

$ cat Makefile

```
.PHONY: all test

all: start test

test: start
    @./start.native get_file_buffer.ml

start:
    ocamlbuild start.native
```

$ make
....

**Use dune(formerly jbuilder) which is far the most coherent build tool for ocaml** these days.

a. Create a `jbuild` file in the same directory as the `*.ml` files.

$cat jbuild

```
(jbuild_version 1)

(executable
 ((name start)))
```

$ jbuilder build start.exe

$ jbuilder exec -- ./start.exe get_file_buffer.ml

If you prefer you can use `make` to drive `dune/jbuilder` by creating a `Makefile`.

$cat Makefile

```
.PHONY: all test

all: start test

test: start
    jbuilder exec -- ./start.exe get_file_buffer.ml

start:
    jbuilder build start.exe
```

$ make

Comment: Thank you for the help @Bikal Lem. I have got the program to compile using the first method you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Writing a correct Makefile for OCaml is complicated: OCaml compilers tend to produce multiple files which is not something that Makefile handles gracefully, moreover the exact dependency graph might depend on the compiler flags (e.g. `-opaque` or `-no-alias-deps`) and the version (bytecode, native without flambda, native with flambda) of the compiler. That's why the easiest solution by far is to use a build system like jbuilder/dune(http://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), or ocamlbuild (https://github.com/ocaml/ocamlbuild/blob/master/manual/manual.adoc).

p.s. : in your case, you are indeed missing the dependency of `main.cmx` to `get_file_buffer.{cmi,cmx}` .

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that `main.cmx` should depend on `get_file_buffer.cmx`. Otherwise `make` might try to compile `main.cmx` first, in which case of course the module `Get_file_buffer` cannot be found because it does not yet exist.

More precisely, the compilation of `main.cmx` also depends on `gen_file_buffer.o`. But as that file is created at the same time as `gen_file_buffer.cmx`, you should be fine. (And to my limited knowledge it is not possible with `make` to specify that a single rule creates more than one file at the same time.)